# How can I send a number from a master and make the slave read it?

Tags: i2c, raspberrypi

I am building a fan controller using an Arduino and a Raspberry Pi (the Pi is the master and the Arduino is the slave). The Raspberry Pi generates random numbers and I want the slave (Arduino) to be able to read the string of numbers and increase the current speed of a pwm fan by the amount read.
How I can read the bits sent over I2c as numbers to allow me to do what I want to do?

Comment: See [I2C Anything](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10896&reply=8#reply8).

Comment: If you are only going to send "random number" why not let the Arduino generate them instead and remove the Pi all together. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/